# Android Display spinners in Ok/Cancel popup dialog

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I want to have a popup dialog with OK/Cancel and two spinners.

(1) Is this possible?

(2) Has this been done in any other apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible take a look at how to implement custom dialogs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog